# Maximum dimension of a subspace of $M_n(\mathbb C)$ containing no invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Do you know a *simple* proof of the fact the maximum dimension of a subspace of $M_n(\mathbb C)$ containing no invertible matrix is $n(n-1)$?

One can see it at least $n(n-1)$ by considering the subspace of all matrix having a zero first row.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/596800/maximal-value-of-dimension?rq=1 (but I don't know if that qualifies as a simple proof...)

Comment: Yes ... I have little hope that there is a simple proof actually ... Thanks. @ArnaudD.